# Lucene как согласовать позицию слова из текста с позицией, которую выдает IndexWriter?

Tags: java, lucene

У меня есть текст он храниться в переменной fileContent:

```
created: 2003-09-22T19:01:14Z
Author: be590_guest

GUERRILLA WAR, COUNTERINSURGENCY, AND STATE 

FORMATION IN OTTOMAN YEMEN
```

Если разделить его на слова с разделителем "пробел" и перевести в объект класса TextWord, а потом попробовать вывести содержимое, то можно увидеть такое:

```
TextWord[0]: created:
TextWord[1]: 2003-09-22T19:01:14Z
Author:
TextWord[2]: be590_guest



TextWord[3]: 
GUERRILLA
TextWord[4]: WAR,
TextWord[5]: COUNTERINSURGENCY,
TextWord[6]: AND
TextWord[7]: STATE
TextWord[8]: 

FORMATION
TextWord[9]: IN
TextWord[10]: OTTOMAN
TextWord[11]: YEMEN
```

После я создаю индекс по переменной fileContent:

```
//Создание индекса по данным из файла
    public void createIndex(String content) throws IOException {
        
        IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
        try (IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(this.memoryIndex, indexWriterConfig)) {
            Document doc = new Document();
            FieldType type = new FieldType();
            type.setStoreTermVectors(true);
            type.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
            type.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(true);
            type.setStored(true);
            type.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
            Field fieldStore = new Field("tags", content, type); //В поле "tags" записываются данные из переменной content
            doc.add(fieldStore);
            writer.addDocument(doc);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Для этого я использую new StandardAnalyzer().

После создания индекса, я хочу найти слово "state" в тексте fileContent, используя этот созданный индекс:

```
        String query_pattern = "state"; //Что хочу найти в тексте
        
        DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(this.memoryIndex); //Взять индекс из памяти
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader); //Создать поисковик по индексу

        //Поиск по одному слову
        Query query = new QueryParser("tags", analyzer).parse(query_pattern.toLowerCase()); //Запрос на поиск слова по полю tags
        TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 1); //Результат поиска
        
        for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : results.scoreDocs) { //Если слово было найдено, то...

            Fields termVs = reader.getTermVectors(scoreDoc.doc);
            Terms f = termVs.terms("tags");

            BytesRef ref = new BytesRef(query_pattern.toLowerCase()); //Шаблон в байтах для проверки

            TermsEnum te = f.iterator();
            PostingsEnum docsAndPosEnum = null;
            if (te.seekExact(ref)) { //Если нашли такое слово из шалона, то...

                //Узнать позицию и число повторений этого слова
                docsAndPosEnum = te.postings(docsAndPosEnum, PostingsEnum.ALL);
                int nextDoc = docsAndPosEnum.nextDoc();
                assert nextDoc != DocIdSetIterator.NO_MORE_DOCS;
                final int freg = docsAndPosEnum.freq();
                final int pos = docsAndPosEnum.nextPosition();
                final int o = docsAndPosEnum.startOffset();

                System.out.println("Word: " + ref.utf8ToString());
                System.out.println("[1] of [" + freg + "] Position: " + pos + ", startOffset: " + o + " length: " + ref.length + " Freg: " + freg);

                if (freg > 1) { //Число повторений слова в тексте
                    int i = 2;
                    for (int iter = 1; iter <= freg - 1; iter++) {
                        final int posNext = docsAndPosEnum.nextPosition();
                        System.out.println("[" + i + "] of [" + freg + "] Possition: " + posNext);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Слово находиться и выводится его позиция:

```
Word: state
Position: 12
```

Я захожу в свой TextWord а там по позиции 12 нет такого слова, или нет такой позиции, тогда я вывожу все term из индекса и их позиции, ранжирую их порядку:

```
            Fields termVs = reader.getTermVectors(scoreDoc.doc);
            Terms f = termVs.terms("tags");
            TermsEnum te = f.iterator();
            PostingsEnum docsAndPosEnum = null;
            BytesRef bytesRef;

            while ((bytesRef = te.next()) != null) { //Пройтись по всем словам из индекса

                docsAndPosEnum = te.postings(docsAndPosEnum, PostingsEnum.ALL);
                int nextDoc = docsAndPosEnum.nextDoc();
                assert nextDoc != DocIdSetIterator.NO_MORE_DOCS;
                final int fr = docsAndPosEnum.freq();
                final int pos = docsAndPosEnum.nextPosition();
                final int o = docsAndPosEnum.startOffset();

                System.out.println("Word: " + bytesRef.utf8ToString());
                System.out.println("Position: " + pos + ", startOffset: " + o + " length: " + bytesRef.length + " Freg: " + fr);
                sortIndexWord.put(bytesRef.utf8ToString(), pos);

                if (fr > 1) {
                    for (int iter = 1; iter <= fr - 1; iter++) {
                        int posNext = docsAndPosEnum.nextPosition();
                        //System.out.println("Possition: " + posNext);
                        sortIndexWord.put(bytesRef.utf8ToString()+String.valueOf(iter), posNext);
                    }

                }

            }
```

И получаю такие данные:

```
IndexWord: [0]: created
IndexWord: [1]: 2003
IndexWord: [2]: 09
IndexWord: [3]: 22t19
IndexWord: [4]: 01
IndexWord: [5]: 14z
IndexWord: [6]: author
IndexWord: [7]: be590_guest
IndexWord: [8]: guerrilla
IndexWord: [9]: war
IndexWord: [10]: counterinsurgency
IndexWord: [12]: state
IndexWord: [13]: formation
IndexWord: [15]: ottoman
IndexWord: [16]: yemen
```

Видно, что он удалил слово And из 11 позиции и State стал 12, но если я просто попробую вывести токены, используя также как и при индексе new StandardAnalyzer():

```
public List<String> analyze(String text, Analyzer analyzer) throws IOException {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream("tags", text);
        CharTermAttribute attr = tokenStream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        tokenStream.reset();
        while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
            result.add(attr.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }

    List<String> list = analyze(myContent, new StandardAnalyzer());
    for(int ik = 0 ; ik <= list.size()-1; ik++){
        System.out.println("ListWord["+ik+"]: "+list.get(ik));
    }
```

То можно увидеть:

```
ListWord[0]: created
ListWord[1]: 2003
ListWord[2]: 09
ListWord[3]: 22t19
ListWord[4]: 01
ListWord[5]: 14z
ListWord[6]: author
ListWord[7]: be590_guest
ListWord[8]: guerrilla
ListWord[9]: war
ListWord[10]: counterinsurgency
ListWord[11]: state
ListWord[12]: formation
ListWord[13]: ottoman
ListWord[14]: yemen
```

Слово And опять было удалено, но при этом у меня все равно другие индексы и мне никак не угадать какие слова он удалил, а какие - нет.

---

Вопрос, вот в чем, как согласовать позицию слова из текста с позицией, которую выдает IndexWriter? Покажите как быть, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я захожу в свой TextWord а там по позиции 12

lucene ничего не знает про ваш `TextWord`. И `position` не имеет к нему отношения. Это некий абстрактный идентификатор позиции в тексте (в простом случае можно считать, что это номер токена, но все зависит от анализатора, изменятся его настройки и этот номер утратит свой смысл).

> Слово And опять было удалено, но при этом у меня все равно другие индексы и мне никак не угадать какие слова он удалил, а какие - нет

Вам это и не нужно. Процесс анализа нужен для того, чтоб lucenе знал, как нужно разбивать текст на слова. На вход вы подаете текст, а ищете слова, да еще иногда не одно слово, а несколько. Анализатор и задает правила, что является разделителем, нужно ли индексировать слова з дефисом по отдельности и/или вместе и т.п. К позиции же совпадения в тексте, это не имеет отношения, т.к. анализатор преобразовывает входной текст - какие-то слова может преобразовать (скажем изменить регистр или заменить аббревиатуру), какие-то слова может выбросить, что-то может склеить, и даже вставить новые слова из кусочков существующих. Вам же нужна позиция в *оригинальном* тексте, т.е. до обработки его анализатором.

Главная проблема в том, что из `PostingsEnum`  вам нужны не `positions`, а `offsets`. `startOffset` указывает на индекс начала, а `endOffset` на индекс конца в *сохраненном значении поля*, т.е. в том, которое вы передавали при индексации и которое хранится в индексе. Само значение можно достать так:

```
int docid = scoreDoc.doc;
Document doc = searcher.doc(docid);
String text = doc.get("tags");   // сохраненное значение поля
String match = text.substring(docsAndPosEnum.startOffset(), docsAndPosEnum.endOffset());
```

Посмотрите на этот пример https://howtodoinjava.com/lucene/lucene-search-highlight-example/ и на [исходники](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/main/lucene/highlighter/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.java) `Highligher`-a, а именно как он использует `offsets` для того, чтоб достать значения для подсветки.